# how to run a lot of iced nodeunit tests

Tags: gruntjs, nodeunit, iced-coffeescript

When I run iced nodeunit test ...

```
$ nodeunit path/to/file/file_name.iced
```

... it's ok.

When I run a lot of coffee script tests ...

```
 grunt.initConfig({
   nodeunit: {
     coffee: ['path/to/coffee/nodeunit/tests/**/*_test.coffee']
   }
 });

 $ grunt nodeunit:coffee
```

...  it's ok. 
But when I try to run set of iced nodeunit tests with `grunt nodeunit` ...

```
grunt.initConfig({
  nodeunit: {
    iced: ['path/to/iced/nodeunit/tests/**/*_test.iced']
  }
});
```

... got errors: `Fatal error: Unexpected string`. Seemingly `gruntjs` don't understand `iced coffeescript`.

So how to run a lot of iced nodeunit tests? 
May be without `grunt-contrib-nodeunit`, but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grunt-contrib-nodeunit DOES support iced coffee (see this [issue](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/pull/184))

your test-code does not seem to be valid iced-coffee!